# While loops in SCSS to produce circles for an animation

Tags: beginner, iteration, sass

I've finally written my first loop in SCSS, trying to avoid it for quite some time since I thought it was unnecessary (was writing vanilla CSS not so long ago, so I was used to manual work).

However, I feel this code isn't very optimized, especially since I seem to need two different `while`-loops (one for divs from center to left, and one for divs to the right).

**Demo** is available at http://codepen.io/pestbarn/pen/myqvEq

**The loops**

I found myself needing an `@if` condition for tweaking the margin for the center div by just `1vh`.

```
// generate 6 circles from center to left
$i: 6;
$s: 38;
$t: -19;
$l: -90;
$z: 2;
@while $i > 0 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    @include sqsize($s);
    margin-top: $t+vh;
    margin-left: $l+vh;
    z-index: $z;
  }
  $i: $i - 1;
  $s: $s - 2;
  $t: $t + 1;
  @if $l == -30 {
    $l: $l + 16
  } @else {
    $l: $l + 15;
  }
  $z: $z + 1;
}
// generate 5 circles to the right
$i: 11;
$s: 38;
$t: -19;
$l: 52;
$z: 2;
@while $i > 6 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    @include sqsize($s);
    margin-top: $t+vh;
    margin-left: $l+vh;
    z-index: $z;
  }
  $i: $i - 1;
  $s: $s - 2;
  $t: $t + 1;
  $l: $l - 13;
  $z: $z + 1;
}
```

Is there perhaps a way of only needing to write one `while`-loop for this? From left to right, the div sizes (where 1 is smallest and 6 is largest) go `6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6`, in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rewriting it like this - much more compact and clean. If there are further ways to optimize this, I'm open to suggestions!

```
// generate circles from left to right

$i: 1; $s: 38; $t: -19; $l: -89.3; $z: 2;

@while $i <= 11 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) { 
        @include sqsize($s);
        margin-top: $t+vh;
        margin-left: $l+vh;
        z-index: $z;
    }
    $i: $i + 1;
    $z: $z + 1;
    $b: $i <= 6;
    $l: if($b, $l + 15, $l + 13);
        // <= 6 - circles are coming from the left
        // > 6 - circles are going to the right
    $s: if($b, $s - 2, $s + 2);
        // same logic as above - decrease size towards middle
        // and increase size after passing the middle
    $t: if($b, $t + 1, $t - 1);
        // —〃—
}
```